How to grep a specific data
I want to grep python extensions with their names in a large data of words and sentences, and I tried with find and grep commands but I couldn't do that. Can anyone tell me what should I do?
By the way i am doing this on mac terminal and my command was this:
cat tampers.txt | grep *.py

and after that i tried this :
grep .py tampers.txt

but it only shows me .py extensions
and i just want the .py with their names for put it on a another text file.

Assuming you want to extract the filenames which have .py extension
out of "tampers.txt" file and each filename does not include whitespace
chracters, try: grep -oE "[^[:blank:]]*\.py" tampers.txt.

You can try using this command wich will put all the file with the extension .py in a text file:
grep '\.py' tampers.txt > python_files.txt


i tried but output was the all of data  on that file not only .py file names.

maybe you could try with other tools like awk or sed?
